# problems with DoCmd.OpenReport

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a button on a form that opens a report. The report open as it should whenever there is data however when there is no data in the report I get an error and the debugger takes me to this line
`DoCmd.OpenReport "FilesToBeReturnedReport", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal`

Here is the entire code:

```
`With Me
    If ((IsNull(.StartDate) Or .EndDate = "")) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "You must enter report start period", vbOKOnly, "Required Data!"
    ElseIf (IsNull(.EndDate) Or .EndDate = "") Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "You must enter report end date", vbOKOnly, "Reqired Data"
    ElseIf (.StartDate > .EndDate) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "The report start date must be earlier than the end date", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenReport "FilesToBeReturnedReport", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
    End If
End With`
```

I need to complete this by tomorrow so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Access reports have a NoData event. You can put the actions you want to run in the case of no data there. If you set Cancel to True inside the NoData event, the report will not open or print. If you leave Cancel as its default False, the report will open as it does now.

That said, you also need to catch this error when using DoCmd.OpenReport:

```
On Error Goto ReportFail
DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, acViewPreview

ExitHere:
Exit Sub

ReportFail:
If Err=2501 Then
  'OpenReport was canceled
  Err.Clear
  Resume ExitHere
Else
  MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: is mostly correct except the Err number should be 2501.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really extremely experienced with vba in access but why don't you try puttting

DoCmd.OpenReport "FilesToBeReturnedReport", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal

after the

```
End with
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but it didn't work. What I did was to use the 'On Load' event procedure to run a count of the record and close if = 0. and return a message to the user. thanks for your efforts nonetheless.

Comment: sorry about that glad you were able to fix it @kefash